# Android 2x2 rows of images that automatically scale

Tags: java, android

I am looking for the best solution to create 2x2 rows that automatically scale. The problems I have faced so far, is the left image being full size, and the right being downsized a lot.

The pictures will be 400x400 pixels, and need to be displayed probably on all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) will work fine, It keep fixed number of columns and with [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) you have to deal with adapter and others stuff to achieve.

Below is an simple example to create 2x2 columns with Imageview.

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: its working with @drawable/ic_launcher, because ic_launcher has small size, but if we are putting 2 images with big and different size in these Imageview then it only shows "android:id="@+id/button2" ImageView image.

Comment: layout_weight is given, it will auto scale equally.

Comment: yes you are right, but i have tried by using 2 images with different size, one has 900 x 1440 and second has 338 x 450 size. it only shows big image.

Comment: we should handle this by using LayoutParams. i have created one 2 x 2 demo by using LinearLayout and ImageView. download from this link : http://www.mediafire.com/?ouav9ucj377197k i think it might help you. i am just creating this sample demo code.

Comment: The height doesn't scale. i Have tried android:layout_height="fill_parent"

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use Android `TableLayout` in your XML layout file.

Note: `GridView` would be appropriate if there were a variable number of rows in your table.

**2x2 Example**:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```